# VisualStudioCode doesn't accept my JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm new to StackOverflow but I don't really know how everything works here but I have a question.

When I try to create a JavaScript file in VSC, it automatically converts it to a Typescript, but I need the JavaScript file and not TypeScript. I asked on some other platforms but they said it's not really a problem. For me, it is because TypeScript doesn't accept everything JavaScript does. And after a ton of resources, I found out that it can't accept everything unless you change some things, etc. I'm just hopeless right now and really could use some help or an explanation.

It would be great if someone could help me here

Comment: At the bottom of the window there should be a button that says "TS TypeScript" (or something similar), if you click that button you should be able to select JavaScript instead. If the file has the `.ts` extension then it will usually be automatically interpreted as TypeScript, and a `.js` file normally interpreted as JavaScript. I can't answer - unfortunately - as I don't have access to VS Code currently, so I can't verify my suggestion.

Comment: OMG !! Thank you it actually worked. Thank you sooo much 